# Git fatal error while cloning

Tags: git, github, repository, git-clone

Hey when i try to clone an repository it says:

> `fatal: Repository "..." not found`

I tryed nearly everything to solve this issue but nothing works. Now i asked a workmate to try the same command, and at his computer it works. Can someone help?

The Console whole console output:

```
git clone https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git
cloning into 'jquery' ...
fatal: repository 'http://github.com/jquery/jquery.git/' not found
```

EDIT:

I checked the link and when i put it into my browser its opening the repository! And i uploaded a picture of the console:
[image]

EDIT:

If i try it whit ssh:

> git ls-remote git@github.com:jquery/jquery.git

it works, but it still doesnt work whit https, and i need that https works for bower package installs!

Comment: Are you sure that is the real command and output? I ask because the git clone command you're showing does in fact work. Make sure to double- and triple-check for spelling errors.

Comment: What version of git are you using? That doesn't look like complete output from a git command using versions I'm familiar with

Comment: btw, I'd look for networking issues.  (Bad etc/hosts entry? DNS problem? Problem connecting to github.com?)

Comment: I executed the command in the console of git and in the command promt of windows! Booth are facing the same error as i said in my question. My Git Version is 2.14.1!

Comment: Are your ssh keys configured in github? You can also try using ssh url. I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29558484) , in which OP used ssh url and it started working.

Comment: Yes ssh is configured!

Answer (score 0):

Sure you have used the `https` address? Your errormessage speaks about a `http` remote.

Comment: In my clone command iam executing https but somehow it returns http in the error! Could it be that? And how can i change that?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can check whether repository exists or not by using the command:

```
  git ls-remote https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git
```

In my case i got this output(trimmed):

```
b1b949d35ee995ee75c6968715a7f8c8ea601157        HEAD
e09907ce152fb6ef7537a3733b1d65ead8ee6303        refs/heads/1.12-stable
b14ce54334a568eaaa107be4c441660a57c3db24        refs/heads/2.2-stable
90347a78d69b15a515c462eb378adb7e6067f5dd        refs/heads/killphp
b1b949d35ee995ee75c6968715a7f8c8ea601157        refs/heads/master
295d95a1af40a0e278e197591e0e39ef5e96ea91        refs/pull/1/head
1fe579dc1211f6c6a72cfa46610fdd80c67f469f        refs/pull/10/head
c04500a8347f381b069c036d9ac24b591b3fc6b7        refs/pull/100/head
6db8223b29fbc305e97e5568e425609ed7289a87        refs/pull/1000/head
195a9be29d0d996fb44be1983f19207a84b1766e        refs/pull/1000/merge
ff6319ee7080214ec93ad217dd46ee3af0f606e2        refs/pull/1001/head
81b16266f8c97e4c652688fae4706392496e3f35        refs/pull/1001/merge
3dc0e4c8d46358aae5f171627049bda6b7aa6690        refs/pull/1002/head
0a169f60a540cbd73f964a54fdc52c2e058a3447        refs/pull/1002/merge
245b5f0a92e200b4e58dde9d3b73b70207991a85        refs/pull/1003/head
fe89e8709fc53e9f4d8bb8381944cd35fccd7e09        refs/pull/1003/merge
8ece5ec71e5b41cd8f4f30688e33822dd3d95841        refs/pull/1004/head
020d586a690c4afd8e7e89b66d933f6a11283401        refs/pull/1004/merge
e31189f965843ac450164843cf29f04f3fdf8ad0        refs/pull/1005/head
e48ef5256346efb106411a3bec8c757c2f9eff8e        refs/pull/1005/merge
216c02099aebe9302ae356e747cd7a8506c47a55        refs/pull/1006/head
9bb1b1aea92cdf45a9232015b04f47b16a8bfa3a        refs/pull/1006/merge
5816980e5d70cda3bdb07adc4bb4f0decf892934        refs/pull/1007/head
ee08ede0cefc1dd427a44307048abf52b5af9e56        refs/pull/1007/merge
4dbe3aeb0cfaba781b51b4c4d3d83db418d009aa        refs/pull/1008/head
477310f3e807da101bf6f3420886f50434ac1763        refs/pull/1008/merge
719df2b3fafef0248eeecaf160a3cd6738d9df8b        refs/pull/1009/head
```

I tried cloning the repository both with `http` and `https`(in both cases i was able to clone this repository); i didn't encountered the problem you're facing. Since your colleague was also able to clone it, i would suggest to check for any typos in the link of the repository.

Comment: I copy pasted your command and it says the same error! I execute the command whit https too. But in the error it returns http!

Comment: Could you paste the entire output of all your attempts again, on pastebin or something? I think it might be a networking issue then as mentioned in comments by  Mark Adelsberger.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are using the root url of the repository. you will see something like clone or download. fatal error usually occurs when you try cloning sub-directories inside the repository.